# Android Emulator is not responding V4.2.1

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, android-emulator

I've done a lot of researches trying to find a solution and eventually I didn't.
It was working perfectly until I update Android Studio to latest version 4.2.1
my PC SSD512 core i 5 intel and in good conditions
please help me

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPEoj.png)

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution

You should go to >> 1. Windows features on and off
2. Make sure that Hyper-V Check box is marked if not mark it. then restart your pc